# Laravel validation of pivot table value

Tags: php, laravel

I have a pivot table in laravel that has some extra data.

I've been looking around and could not find a mechanism for validating that data, short of writing one myself. But if there's an existing one there already, that would be reinventing the wheel.

Any idea how I could apply the laravel validation to the pivot table as well?

Thanks!

Comment: what validation you want to apply ? like unique ?

Answer (score 0):

Laravel's Validator takes fields and the rules to check the fields against as simple assoc arrays. You **[apply](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/validation#other-validation-approaches)** them exactly like for form data. So, consider this kind of logic:

```
$user = App\User::find(1);

foreach ($user->roles as $role) {
    $field = array('rolename' = > $role->pivot->name);
    $rule = array('rolename' => 'required|alpha');

    $validator = Validator::make($field, $rule);

    if ($validator->fails()) {
        // Handle the validation error...
    }
}
```

I see 2 problems with this approach, though: first, the validator runs in a loop, which might be a performance issue if you need to validate lots of pivot entries. Second, I really think you should validate the pivot entries **before** you store them.

Could be there's a way to get all the pivot entries at once, without the loop, but I'm not sure about that one.